# Congruences and the integers as an integral domain

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integral-domain

I am trying to prove the following: If $p$ is prime, then the only solutions of the congruence $x^2 \equiv x$ (mod $p$) are those integers $x$ such that $x \equiv 0$ (mod $p$) or $x \equiv 1$ (mod $p$).

My approach is this. Given $x^2 \equiv x$ (mod $p$), then $x^2 - x = pk$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. So $x(x-1) = pk \equiv 0$ (mod $p$). It follows by the fact that the integers are an integral domain, $x \equiv 0$ or $x \equiv 1$ are the only two solutions to $x^2 \equiv x$ (mod $p$).

Is this a valid proof?

Comment: Does it "follow by the fact that the integers are an integral domain" that $x(x-1)\equiv 0$ mod $n$ implies $x\equiv 0$ or $x\equiv 1$ mod $n$, if $n$ is composite? You need to recognize what's special about $p$ being prime.

Comment: No, it follows either by $\,\Bbb Z/p\,$ is an integral domain, so $\,x(x\!-\!1)\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\,x\equiv 0\,$ or $\,x\!-\!1\equiv 0,\,$ or, equivalently, by prime $\,p\mid x(x\!-\!1)\,\Rightarrow\,p\mid x\,$ or $\,p\mid x\!-\!1.\ \ $

Comment: If it followed from the fact the integers are an integral domain, then presumably $x(x-1)=\equiv 0\pmod{15}$ would only have $2$ solutions mod $15$. But for example $x=5$ is a solution. The primality of $p$ needs to be used.

Comment: @ Andre Nicolas - I don't understand how $x = 5$ is a solution to $x(x-1) \equiv 0$ (mod 15) since $5 \times 4 = 20 \equiv 5$ (mod 15).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is valid, but here you re using the fact that the integers mod p (set of residue classes mod p) form an integral domain!

Comment: How about this as a proof:

$x^2 - x = x(x-1) = pk$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $p | x$ or $p | (x-1)$. In the former case, $x \equiv 0$ (mod p) and in the latter case $p | (x - 1)$ so $x \equiv 1$ (mod p).

Comment: Perfectly perfect!